# can't npm install this project

Tags: npm, npm-install

first of all im not a developper so please keep it simple. Also english isn't my main language so don't hesitate to ask me if im not clear on something.

I need to use a tool availaible here https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS but when i try to npm install after cloning it it show me somes errors that i can't really understand.

Im using npm 6.14.4 if thats help

Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VESzv.png

Comment: And I also can't say Hi at the start of my thread it automatically deletes it I don't know why, so sorry if it might seem harsh

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That is an intended feature -- this is a Q/A site, where the questions are designed to help other developers and one of the intentional features helps keep down clutter by preventing such; also please edit your post to include the errors in a code block instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is at fault; not your setup. Please [set up an issue on the GitHub](https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS/issues).

-ALSO- note that `cd` is a shell builtin, not an executable, so to cd to /root/ you would need a root shell with `sudo su -` or `sudo -s`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to set up an issue right now. And don't worry about the cd I don't have problems with it, I just wanted to see if you were able to access it with the default user in Ubuntu server.

Comment: If this helped; please accept my answer.

Comment: Also; it appears a project contributor has answered your issue; use yarn instead.